# Delete Content of file after a particulate string match

Tags: java

I want to delete the content of the file after a particular string do what i did i have made a temp file and copy the data in to that and after completion renaming hat file.

But when i tried I am not able t rename the file and as well as can't delete the old file.My code is given below and output surprising how can last line be called if it is in loop.

**UPDATED**

```
 File inputFile = new File(propertiesFilePath+"/"+fileName);
    File tempFile = new File(propertiesFilePath+"/tempfile.properties");
    BufferedWriter writer=null;
    BufferedReader reader =null;
    System.out.println("Input file "+inputFile.exists()+"   "+tempFile.exists());
    try{
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
    String currentLine=null;    
    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(currentLine.contains(KEY_STORE)) break;
        System.out.println("Lines "+currentLine);
        writer.write(currentLine);
     }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception in deleting config");
    }finally{
        writer.close();
        reader.close();

    }


    System.err.println("Inpute file delete "+inputFile.delete()); 

    return tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```

**output:**

```
Input file true   true
Lines # ----------------------------------------------

Inpute file delete false      Renamed false

Lines # ---------------------------------------------------

Lines # 

Lines # ----------------------------------------------------

Lines #

Lines # --------------------------------------------------------

Lines # ---------------------------------------------------------

Lines # -------------------

Lines #

Lines # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -----------------------

Lines #------------------------------------------------------------------

Lines # ----------------------

Lines -----------------------

Lines
```

i have replced text by(------) but how it is possible to print the Sysout which is outside the look before loop completion.

Is there any better way to achive what I want.

Comment: What exception do you get in the catch block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you have the file open in a BufferedReader.

`File inputFile = new File(propertiesFilePath+"/"+fileName);`

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));`

`return tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);`

You never close `reader`.

Try adding `reader.close()` before you rename/delete the file.

Comment: I have changed the code as per your suggestion but wont work. can you please tell me why the Sysout written outside the loop printing in between ?

Comment: it worked after putting finally{
            try{
            if(writer!=null)writer.close();
            if(reader!=null)reader.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.err.println("Exception in closing "+e.getMessage());
            }
        } in code.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine, only thing I noticed tempFile.renameTo(inputFile) is happening twice, in these two lines:

```
System.err.println("Inpute file delete "+inputFile.delete()+"      Renamed "+tempFile.renameTo(inputFile)); 
return tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```

The only reason I can think of is that the process might not have permission to perform these operations, so both rename and delete are failing.

Please check permission, hoping this helps.

Cheers !!

Comment: I have removed one check updated code. How can i check the permission ?

Comment: Where is this code running windows/linux/Unix ? In case it is running in Unix/Linux, goto to parent of directory where rename/delete operation is happening, run "ls - ltr", it will give your permissions, if it is test environment giving full permission will help to confirm the issue.